# Constructing routing matrix based on given dataset with constraints

Tags: r, routes, bigdata

I am working on a data frame named `dbus` that describes the fixed-routes of a public bus over certain time periods. A small portion of the data frame is shown below. The meaning of this data frame is pretty simple: column Stop.Name labels all the bus stops a bus would visit, in the same order as shown in the dataset, during a particular date.

```
    Date        DOW        Trip.Time      Stop.Name    
   <chr>        <chr>      <chr>          <chr>                 
 1 01-OCT-2016  Saturday  05:55           Davis CTA St             
 2 01-OCT-2016  Saturday  05:55           Benson / Davis            
 3 01-OCT-2016  Saturday  05:55           Davis / Maple             
 4 01-OCT-2016  Saturday  05:55           Davis / Oak               
 5 01-OCT-2016  Saturday  05:55           Davis Ridge
 6 01-OCT-2016  Saturday  05:55           Davis Asbury             
 7 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    05:55           Asbury Church           
 8 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    05:55           Church Wesley             
 9 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    05:55           Church Ashla
10 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    05:55           Church Florence   
11 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    06:55           Church Britt            
12 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    06:55           Asbury Road           
13 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    06:55           Church Wesley             
14 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    06:55           Bryan St
15 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    05:55           Church Florence
16 02-OCT-2016  Sunday    05:55           Church Ashla
```

**My objective**: Write an **R code** to re-construct the routing matrix A, preferably only based on ONE columns: stop.name (so, ignore the remaining columns). The routing matrix A = (a_{ij}) (i,j are indices for stops) would contain entries of 1 and 0, but based on the following rules:

1. If there exists a path (indirect path is ok) between stop i and j, then a_(ij)=1. Otherwise, a_(ij) = 0.
2. Each row of the matrix, would be labeled as 1 of two types: i_ON or i_OFF. For example, row 1 would be labeled as (Davis CTA St)_ON, which means only entries on row 1 and columns with label "Davis CTA St j" where j is the name of another bus stop connected to Davis CTA St (so, j would be Benson/Davis, Davis/Maple, Davis/Oak,..., Davis Asbury) are equal to 1. The remaining entries on row 1 = 0.
3. Based on definition, a_(ij) and a_(ji) might not be equal. For example, during 01-OCT-2016, NO way to go from Davis/Maple to Davis CTA St (i.e, there is NO loop shown in the dataset during that particular date). On the other hand, there are loops during 02-OCT-2016.
4. Columns of the matrix are denoted by all **CONNECTED** pairs (indirectly connected pairs must be included too) of stop names presented in the dataset.

**My heuristic algorithm:** First, I create a zero-entry matrix A with row x column = (2*number of stops)x(all connected pairs of **unique** stops) (for the dataset above, I have 13 **unique stops** and 63 **connected pairs** out of 78 possible pairs. I can only came up with the number of connected pairs mainly through inspection only). So A has the size **26*63**. Now, for each row of A, I want to change the corresponding entries into 1 based on rule 2. The expected output would be

```
A = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0.... 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.... 0 ----> All zeros since the 
                                    bus does not go INTO Davis CTA St
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1.... 0


     0  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0...1 1]` ---> Last 5 entries = 
    1s since the bus goes from Church Florence to Church Ashla, which is 
    connected to 4 other bus stops
```

where columns **1 -> 63** is the set of (indirectly/directly) connected bus stops: {Davis CTA St -> Benson/Davis, Davis CTA St -> Davis Maple, Davis CTA St -> Davis/Oak, ..., Church Florence -> Ashbury Road}. The rows 1 -> 26 would be labeled Davis CTA St_ON, Davis CTA St_Off, Benson/Davis ON, Benson/Davis OFF,..., Bryan St OFF.

Note that looking at the routing matrix A above, **rules 2 & 4** can be coded into the following rule: if stop i and j are connected, and stop j and k are connected, then i are connected to j. This means for the row `i_IN`, if the entries correspond to columns `ij` and `jk` are 1, then entry in column `ik` = 1 (so, an `IF` statement here is enough). This means to fill out each row efficiently, we must first obtain the set of **DIRECTLY connected, unique** pairs of bus stops. The set of **indirectly connected** pairs then are obtained from the other set, by using the `IF` statement above. Once we obtain these 2 sets, for each `i_IN` or `i_OUT` row, we just check one of these two sets only (depending on IN or OUT row status), and fill out the entries under every columns appearing in that set with 1. The remaining entries for that `i_IN` or `i_OUT` row remains zero.

**My questions:** Based on the *heuristic* algorithm above, I am still struggled to make a working code. In particular, how do I write an efficient code in R to perform the following tasks:

1. Going through each row of the column `Stop.Name`, record all the **directly connected, unique** pairs of stops (so, no repetition for pairs allowed).
2. List out all **indirectly connected** pairs without overkilling R, since my dataset is 6M+ rows?
3. How do I code the rules for filling out the 1s on the right columns for our giant routing matrix, assume that all the odd rows (rows 1,3,5,...) correspond to status "i_IN", while all the even rows (rows 2,4,6,...) correspond to status "i_OUT".

Given all the information, could someone please help me with any of the tasks above, even only with the data-frame above? I am stuck on task 1 as I could not see how to prevent the repetition from occuring;p Task 2 is tough, as `FOR` loop takes forever. Without those 2, task 3 is impossible to solve;p

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with either 1,2 or 3 above?? I am stuck on this problem for quite sometime, so please help out if you could;p